# Formal Language $\gamma$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, formal-languages

Suppose a formal language $\gamma$ is defined with $\Sigma=\left\{M,I,U\right\}$ and  the following rules:

let $x,y \in \gamma$

1. $MI$ is in the language
2. If $xI$ is in the language then so is $xIU$
3. If $xIIIy$ is in the language then so is xUy
4. If $Mx$ is in the language is then so is $Mxx$
5. If $xUy$ is in the language then so is $xy$

The following theorem has been stated in our course notes:
If $xIII$ is in $\gamma$ so is $x$

I have tried playing around with the rules of the language but I haven't been able to get the desired result, could someone show me how?

Comment: Also, if your teacher didn't acknowledge the inspiration for this exercise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$y$ can be the empty string.